# Tomcat webapp hangs at startup due to db-connection

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, sybase

We have deployed a war file to tomcat container (java/hibernate web application). When starting tomcat, the deployment process freezes at the point where the Database Connection is being initialized. And then, tomcat server never starts. It's the company's test database which fails on startup, when changing to the development server, it works fine. However, I can connect to the test database using the db-visualiser tool.

Here is what we can see in the catalina log, when launching tomcat.

```
15:16:59.481 [Thread-1] INFO  o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 64 - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
15:16:59.481 [Thread-1] INFO  o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 65 - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
15:16:59.482 [Thread-1] INFO  o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 68 - autocommit mode: false
15:16:59.562 [Thread-1] INFO  o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 103 - using driver: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver at URL: jdbc:sybase:Tds:servername:5000/dbname
15:16:59.563 [Thread-1] INFO  o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 109 - connection properties: {user=username, password=password}
```

The environments are as follows: Java6, hibernate,  tomcat6, sybase

Comment: It seems your configuration of war file is the culprit for your local connections. As you said, the same works on Dev-Server, make changes to the local server settings, and the catch is look at you dbVisualizer connection how it works, and try to figure out the problem using same parameters again in local server.

Comment: Thanks. The connection parameteres has not been changed and matches with the settings in dbvisualiser. Usually, if the connection settings are wrong the application throw an exception. In this case, nothing really happens.

Comment: Could it be related to hibernate? Ref the first log output: 

15:16:59.481 [Thread-1] INFO o.h.c.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure 64 - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

Comment: can you post the complete and fresh log, right after the deployment process starts and till the point it freezes. The logs you posted seem insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the log file on the server was takling too much space. It was deleted and the server became responsive again